# Sorting Y-axis of barplot based on the decresing value of last facet grid in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, facet

**Question**:
I am trying to sort the Y-axis of the barplot based on the decreasing value of the last facet group "Step4" with having a common Y-axis label. There are suggestions for ordering all facet groups within themselves but how to do with the common y-axis label and values of one facet group. I have attached a sample data and code for the initial plot to understand the question.
Thanks in advance.

**Data**:
[Download the sample data here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/56xvv94g3my0n6k/sample_data.csv?dl=0)

**Code**:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

#reading data
data <- read.csv(file = "./sample_data.csv", stringsAsFactors = TRUE)

#reshaping data in longer format using reshape::melt
data.melt <- melt(data)

#plotting the data in multi-panel barplot
ggplot(data.melt, aes(x= value, y=reorder(variable, value))) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = Days), width = 0.7) +
  facet_grid(.~step, scales = "free")+
  theme_pubr() + 
  labs(x = "Number of Days", y = "X")
```

**Graph**: [Barplot Graph for the sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIVBu.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summarise the values for last `'step'` and extract the levels from the data.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

lvls <- data.melt %>%
  arrange(step) %>%
  filter(step == last(step)) %>%
  #Or
  #filter(step == 'Step4') %>%
  group_by(variable) %>%
  summarise(sum = sum(value)) %>%
  arrange(sum) %>%
  pull(variable)

data.melt$variable <- factor(data.melt$variable, lvls)

ggplot(data.melt, aes(x= value, y= variable)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = days), width = 0.7) +
  facet_grid(.~step, scales = "free")+
  theme_pubr() + 
  labs(x = "Number of Days", y = "X")
```

[image]